# React, JSX: Как прикрепить ссылку на объект внутри тега?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Доброе утро. 
Я создаю комбобокс с помощью тега `<select>` и хочу, чтоб каждая из опций данного комбобокса содержала ссылку на объект, за который она отвечает.

У меня есть `<option key = {i} value={i} }>{item.name}</option>`

и есть, соответственно, сам item:

```
{
    id : ...,
    name: ...,
    date: ...,
    timePeriod: {},
    manager: ...,
}
```

Каким образом следует создать и передать ссылку на item?

Спасибо! ^^

Comment: что вам даст эта ссылка на объект? Как хранятся эти объекты?

Comment: и не используйте индекс в качестве ключа https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Объекты хранятся в массиве - ссылка даст возможность обращаться к доп. информации в объекте при обработке формы без лишних усилий. Возможно, это можно сделать как-то ещё, но я не знаю как.

Comment: Можете приложить к вопросу структуру этих объектов?

Comment: да - `arr = [{id : ..., name: ..., date: ..., timePeriod: {}  manager: ...,}, {id : ..., name: ..., date: ..., timePeriod: {}  manager: ...,} ]` - как-то так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас вы используете в качестве `value` в `option` переменную `i`, которая по видимому является порядковым номером элемента в массиве.

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно сделать следующее:

Если ваш `item.name` это уникальное значение, то его можно использовать в качестве `value` для `option`

```
<option key={i} value={item.name}>{item.name}</option>
```

Если это не так, то (одно из решений) ваш `item` должен быть объектом, например:

```
item = {name: '...', id: 1}
```

Тогда ваш `option` будет выглядеть так:

```
<option key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
```

Соответственно при выборе определенного элемента вы сможете точно понимать что это за элемент.

Comment: использовать индекс в качестве ключа не `good practies` https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: согласен, исправлю

Comment: Спасибо! Хочу уточнить: объект item содержит в себе разную информацию, и я хотела, чтоб при обработке формы можно было сразу же ее достать (с помощью перехода к объекту по ссылке). Я нуб с реактом, потому что обычно работаю с java - и это то, как я бы делала в java, возможно, тут есть другие варианты?

Comment: @MariaLifshits я бы предложил по id вынимать объект из массива с помощью метода find()

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин - Хорошо. Просто массив находится в одном из дочерних  классов, а обработка формы, соответственно, родительском. 
И я пока что (видимо, тема моего следующего вопроса) пытаюсь обрабатывать форму с помощью getElementsByClassName - и не очень понимаю, каким образом могу при этом получить доступ к массиву (который в дочернем классе).

Comment: @MariaLifshits как массив попадает в дочерние классы и почему не через родительский класс?

Comment: @ThisMan Дочерний класс запрашивает его из JSON файла. 
Получает, обрабатывает с помощью map, превращая его элементы в опции для select тэга

Comment: @MariaLifshits стоит пересмотреть архитектуру, что бы форму загружал родительский класс, если используете `redux` посмотрите в сторону `redux-form`

Comment: @ThisMan - redux не использую (а стоит?) - форму загружал родительский класс - в плане, чтобы создание всего для формы происходило в нем?

Comment: @MariaLifshits да, именно. На счет `redux: стоит или не стоит` зависит от проекта вашего

Comment: @ThisMan - у меня изначально десктопное приложение с кучей логики и минимальным взаимодействием с пользователем, которое сейчас переписываю под веб